# Gatsby- Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\...\gatsby-starter-hello-world\node_modules\postcss\lib'

Tags: node.js, path, gatsby, node-modules

I'm trying to use `sanitize-html` package along with `@types/sanitize-html` for typescript, but it causes the following error-

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js 4:30-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\sapin\Desktop\gatsby-starter-hello-world\node_modules\postcss\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js 14:12-30
 @ ./node_modules/sanitize-html/index.js 7:32-50
 @ ./src/states/BlogsProvider.tsx 12:0-37 103:15-23 104:21-29 105:14-22
 @ ./src/pages/bookmarks.tsx 10:0-51 18:24-32 61:10-18
 @ ./.cache/_this_is_virtual_fs_path_/$virtual/async-requires.js 36:11-38:5
 @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70
```

And I if do `npm i path`, the build time error goes away; but it causes a runtime error-

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at eval (path.js:25)
    at Object../node_modules/path/path.js (commons.js:2976)
    at Object.options.factory (commons.js:4478)
    at __webpack_require__ (commons.js:3881)
    at fn (commons.js:4159)
    at eval (map-generator.js:3)
    at Object../node_modules/postcss/lib/map-generator.js (commons.js:3096)
    at Object.options.factory (commons.js:4478)
    at __webpack_require__ (commons.js:3881)
    at fn (commons.js:4159)
```

Tracing the error line, it is this one that throws the error-

```
var isWindows = process.platform === 'win32';
```

So **in short**, the `sanitize-html` package can't recognize `path` without explicitly installing it. When installed, `path` module can't recognize `process`. How can I fix this?

If not, is there any alternative sanitizing package that supports typescript?

Comment: What about `npm i path-browserify`?

Comment: no it doesn't. it's still the same error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the `v8.2.7`, according to [this comment](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1509#issuecomment-790147136) on GitHub. It seems to be related to the fact that [webpack has removed polyfills in their new `v5` version](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#automatic-nodejs-polyfills-removed), which is a needed dependency of `postcss`, which is also used by `sanitize-html`.

However, if the issue persists, it should be fixed by installing `path-browserify` (by `npm i path-browserify`) and adding the following fallback to webpack's overriding configuration, in your `gatsby-node.js`, [`onCreateWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/) API should work:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
   resolve: {
      fallback: {
        path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      },
    },
  })
}
```

*Source: modified from https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1509#issuecomment-772097567*

I based the answer on the error prompted:

> ```
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>         - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
>         - install 'path-browserify'
> ```